# How to insert small image into corner of a photo with Python Pillow/Image?

Tags: python, image, photo, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to insert a small 252 x 40 px image in the bottom right hand corner of an image using the Pillow library.

Currently, this is how I am trying to do it based off the general method for overlaying an image using Pillow/Image:

```
back = Image.open("images/background.png")
width, height = back.size
image1 = Image.open("images/picture.png")
width1, height1 = image1.size
image1 = image1.convert("RGBA")
back.paste(image, (width - width1, width - height1), image1)
```

Doing this fails to overlay the image. Any tips or other libraries I should use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.

back.paste(image1, (width - width1, height - height1), image2)